# Can I chain commands together with gm for node.js?

Tags: node.js, gm

Can I chain two or more commands together when using `gm`, the GraphicsMagick library for node?

Specifically, I've got an image that I'd like to add text to, then put a watermark on it, but nothing I try seems to work.

I've tried using `gm(image).drawText(0,0,"Text").composite(logo) ...` but that tells me `Unrecognized option (-draw)`. Similar thing when I composite first, then draw text.

I also tried writing the file, then adding the `.drawText` call to the end, but that didn't work.

So can I chain two or more commands together?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but not in this situation. You can make some workaround calling `gm` twice and piping result of first call to another:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const passThrough = new stream.PassThrough();

gm(image).drawText(0, 0, 'Text').stream().pipe(passThrough);
gm(passThrough).composite(logo).write('./output.png', e => console.log(e || 'OK'));
```

To be honest `gm` library sucks. If you don't know anything about GraphicsMagick, `gm` fails to provide good enough abstraction to hide it. You are constantly forced to use constructions like `.resize(240, 240, '!')` which make no sense unless you know syntax of GraphicsMagick's `-resize` option. That's because when you call `gm`'s method it just appends option to some GraphicsMagick command which will be called when you execute `.write()` method, and this is one of these situations when this approach fails. GraphicsMagick provides few commands which supports different options. Most commonly used command is `convert`, it supports for example `-draw` option which is used by `.drawText()` method. Another command is `composite` which is used for merging to images together - it doesn't support `-draw` option. When you use `.composite()` method `gm` uses `composite` command so `.drawText()` methods starts failing. So, you can chain methods like `.drawText()` and `.resize()`, but not `.drawText()` and `.composite()`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I wasn't sure if the async nature of node would get in the way. GM seemed non-ideal, but because I'm watermarking timelapse shots as they're taken, it's a decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toBuffer` and passe it to the next `gm` call (*this particular code is not tested but I have used a similar technic of AWS Lambda*).

```
gm(image)
  .drawText(0, 0, 'Text')
  .toBuffer('PNG',function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) return handle(err);
    gm(buffer)
      .composite(logo)
      .write('./output.png', e => console.log(e || 'OK'));
    console.log('done!');})
```